# Integrating an area bounded by three lines/curves

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the three equations: 
$$y_1 = 25 - x^2$$
$$y_2 = 25 - \frac{25}{3}x$$ 
$$y_3 = 9x - 27$$

I need to find the area bounded by the graphs of each equation  **in the first quadrant**. The graph is shown here: 
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuGkK.png)

Points of Intersection are: (0,25) [y1 & y2] ; (3,0) [y2 & y3] ; (4,9) [y1 & y3]
Thus, the area between these points is the area that needs to be calculated.

If anyone could give some type of direction on how to set up the integral(s), that would be much appreciated. I'm guessing it needs to be split into two or three integrals somehow, but not sure where to start.

Comment: You have a graph, what else do you need?

Comment: I am unsure of how to set up the integral.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Most important is that the area is equal to the integral, if the function $f(x)$ saisfies $f(x)\ge 0$ in the whole interval. If the sign changes, you need two (or more) integrals, from which you take the absolute values.

Comment: The area of the third line in first quadrant is unbounded. Any chance you need to find the area of some shape made by those three curves? For example [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JoZOp.png)?

Comment: @kaster Yes, I am looking for the area of the triangle-like shape that is formed. My current guess is that it just needs to be split into two integrals, where $\int_0^3 (y_1 - y_2)$ + $\int_3^4 (y_1  - y_3)$

Comment: You just need to split your integral into two parts. Like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Iqo.png).

Comment: @Jenna pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, we have $(0, 25)$, $(3, 0)$, and $(4, 9)$ as our intersection points. Therefore, we need to look at the regions of area in between those intersections points.

Between $x=0$ and $x=3$, the area is between the blue curve, $y=25-x^2$, and the purple curve, $y=25-\frac{25x}{3}$. Thus, we have the following integral:
$$\int_0^3 \left(25-x^2-\left(25-\frac{25x}{3}\right)\right)dx$$

Between $x=3$ and $x=4$, the area is between the blue curve, $y=25-x^2$, and the red curve, $y=9(x-3)$. Thus, we have the following integral:
$$\int_3^4 (25-x^2-(9(x-3)))dx$$

Add the two integrals together to get the total area.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem, and I think there might even be a tag for such problems.

Regardless, from the graph you can see that you can construct the area with two integrals (vertical *or* horizontal). I'll illustrate vertical.

The total area between functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $f$ is above $g$, may be written as

$A = \int_a^b (f(x) - g(x) )dx$

Since $y_1$ is the top function for both segments, and the integral must be split at $x=3$, we have

$A = \int_0^3 (y_1 - y_2) dx + \int_3^4 (y_1 - y_3 ) dx$

Then plug in your expressions for $y_1,y_2,y_3$ and integrate.

Substituting, we have

$A = \int_0^3 (\frac{25}{3} x - x^2) dx + \int_3^4 (52 - 9x - x^2 ) dx$

Performing this integral (which is straight forward) yields $A= \frac{110}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your figure, you need to write the integral as a sum of two integrals.

$y = 25 - x^2\rightarrow x=\sqrt{25-y}$ (In the first quadrant).

$y = 25 - \frac{25}{3}x\rightarrow x= 3 - \frac{3}{25}y$.

$y = 9x - 27\rightarrow x=3+ \frac{1}{9}y$.

Now, for $0\leq y\leq 4$, we have $3 - \frac{3}{25}y\leq x\leq 3+ \frac{1}{9}y$, which is the bounds for the first integral.

Next, for $4\leq y\leq 25$, we have $3 - \frac{3}{25}y\leq x\leq 3 - \frac{3}{25}y$, which is the bounds for the second integral.

Your answer is the summation of these two integrals. Please note that I had a double integral in my mind.